# Access list of files and folders of SharePoint 2013 using java client

Tags: java, web-services, sharepoint-2013, webservice-client

Sharepoint 2013 hosted on cloud and its needed office 360 authentication . I want to pull list of files and folders using a java web-service client . Can any one help me with sample code to access it ?

Comment: Did you try http://www.javaworld.com/article/2078906/enterprise-java/java-tip-consuming-sharepoint-web-services-with-a-java-client.html

Comment: Yes hirak, i tried it out and getting 403 Forbidden error in response. As mentioned webservice is hosted on cloud and it needed office 360 authentication. So do have any idea that how do i authenticate with office 360